# Python, different rounding from variable, and hardcoded value

Tags: python, rounding-error

I have a simple math formula that results in a decimal number (0.97745) that I want to round to 4 numbers.
When I do that from my evaluated variable I get (0.9774), but when I hardcode that number into function round(), I get 0.9775

Here is the code

```
zero = 0.9700
effective_beta = 0.00745
loan = {}
loan['beta2'] = 0.0
loan['beta3']  = 0.0
mrktdiff_2 =0.08880400
mrktdiff_3 = 0.026463592000

forecasted_pt = (float(zero) + float(effective_beta) + float(loan['beta2'] or 0.) * float(mrktdiff_2) +
                              float(loan['beta3'] or 0.) * float(mrktdiff_3))
                          
print("before rounding forecastedpt is ")
print(forecasted_pt)
print("after rounding")
print(round(forecasted_pt,4))
print("Dont get this part")
print(round(0.97745,4))
```

The reason why I use the float operators is due to the that these variables are dynamic and sometimes can result in string / null values.

Also when I run the same code in php I get the 0.9775 value for this.

Edit:
I ran the code in katacoda.com editor, and got the following:

```
before rounding forecastedpt is
0.97745
after rounding
0.9774
Dont get this part
0.9775
```

But running it in repl.com I get the first value as: 0.97744999999999 so I guess it could be in the precision of the expression itself

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
zero = 0.9700
effective_beta = 0.00745
loan = {}
loan['beta2'] = 0.0
loan['beta3']  = 0.0
mrktdiff_2 =0.08880400
mrktdiff_3 = 0.026463592000

forecasted_pt = (float(zero) + float(effective_beta) + float(loan['beta2'] or 0.) * float(mrktdiff_2) + float(loan['beta3'] or 0.) * float(mrktdiff_3))

print("before rounding forecastedpt is ")
print(forecasted_pt)
print("after rounding")
print(round(forecasted_pt,5))
numb = round(forecasted_pt,5)
print(round(numb,4))
print("Dont get this part")
print(round(0.97745,4))
```

the output:

```
before rounding forecastedpt is 
0.9774499999999999
after rounding
0.97745
0.9775
Dont get this part
0.9775
```

the round function in any language dont round all entire number its strip the numbers to round only the last number of it.

Answer (score 0):

From the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

**Note:** The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for example, round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float. See [Floating Point Arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues): Issues and Limitations for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
I remember on my statistics class 10 years ago. My Professor has always been advising us to round the calculation up to 6 decimal points as statistics is all about estimation, it counts alot.

```
zero = 0.9700
effective_beta = 0.00745
loan = {}
loan['beta2'] = 0.0
loan['beta3']  = 0.0
mrktdiff_2 =0.08880400
mrktdiff_3 = 0.026463592000

forecasted_pt = round((float(zero) + float(effective_beta) + float(loan['beta2'] or 0.) * float(mrktdiff_2) + float(loan['beta3'] or 0.) * float(mrktdiff_3)),6)


print(round(forecasted_pt,4))
```